# Curve fitting with determination of phonon number associated with each motional state

Tags: python, pandas, curve-fitting, lmfit

I have to write a program in python for curve fitting for at least 20 different parameters of occupation probability as explained below.
[I have added a model for fitting as well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhXTm.png)

Later when from the fit we have the values of fitted occupation probability, we have to determine the mean phonon or vibrational quantum number by thermal population distribution for Pn.

I am attaching a code below just for one parameter P0.

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
from lmfit import Minimizer, Parameters, report_fit

df = pd.read_csv('Fock0_1st BSB.csv')

x = pd.DataFrame(df["Untitled"]).to_numpy()
data = pd.DataFrame(df["Untitled 1"]).to_numpy()
x = [i[0] for i in x]data = [i[0] for i in data]
x = np.asarray (x)
data = np.asarray(data)

x = x/1000
data = abs(data-100)/100

n=0 #Ground State Measurements for n=0

def function(params,x,data):
    v=params.valuesdict()
    model = 0.5*(1+(v['P0'])*np.cos(np.sqrt(n+1)*v['omega0']*v['eta']*x + v['phase'])*np.exp(-(v['gamma']((n+1)**0.7))*x)) - v['decay']*x
    return model - data

params=Parameters()

params.add('P0',value=0.97,min=0.01,max=0.999)
params.add('omega0',value=0.1967,min=0.156,max=0.23,vary=True)
params.add('eta',value=0.0629,min=0.01,max=0.11,vary=True)
params.add('gamma',value=5.6E-4)
params.add('phase',value=0.143)
params.add('decay',value=0.1E-6)

minner = Minimizer(function, params, fcn_args=(x, data))
result = minner.minimize()

final = data + result.residual

report_fit(result)

try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(x, data, '+')# 
    plt.plot(x, final)
    plt.show()
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: I tried to reformat your badly formatted code.  Please check, especially the calculation done in the function and fix so that it is readable.

Comment: The code above written is based on an occupation probability of finding the population in the ground state which is also shown in the image attached above. In the function, I am calling the parameters P0, omega, eta, gamma, phase, and decay.

Comment: I have to write a program by running a loop for say n=20 for several parameters like P0, P1, P2,...., and P20, and these values should be from the fit itself.

Comment: fix the code so that the function runs and does the calculation you intend.  It is not formatted correctly to be valid python code.

Comment: HI, teh code is fine now but the data for value of x is in a file which I dont know how to share. this could be done considering a linear space, x = np.linspace(0,100,12000).

Comment: Ok... well, what is your question?  Is something not working?  If not, what is reported?  I'm sure you can read other SO questions to figure out how to attach or include data if that is important.  It seems strange that your `eta` and `omega` params are not distinguishable - that's likely to cause trouble.  It seems even stranger that you set very precise bounds on many of the parameter values.  Why can `eta` not exceed 0.11?

Comment: Hi, the question is that I have to run a for loop to design the same program for n values of parameter Pn where currently I have it for P0. I have tried the same but problem is that some of the values for parameter Pn are very low from the fit. we have to make one thing clear also the summation of Pn should be 1. Eta can be fixed as well which is 0.0629. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but that is actually not a question. You set up a fit, you ran that fit.  You do not show or post data and do not show or post results from the fit.  I have no idea what your parameter values should be.  If you want further help, you have to ask a question that can be answered.